# Vimscript - Programmatically get colors from colorscheme

Tags: editor, vim

I'm trying to create an autocmd in Vimscript which sets a few attributes of the colorscheme as I want them. Specifically, I'm trying to make the `NonText` background have the same color as the regular background.

The problem is, I have no idea how to get a colorscheme's background color from within vimscript.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit:**

So here's what I'm trying to achieve. Actually a few things:

1. Originally, I was trying to hide the "~" that's in front of all non-existant lines. Someone suggested setting it as the same color as the background, so I added an autocmd that did this: `hi NonText guifg=bg`.
2. After doing that, I realized that some colorschems have a different background color for the regular lines and the "non-existant" part of the buffer. This is a problem, since my autocmd sets the NonText color to be the same as the regular background, not the special "non-existant" background.

   Also, I decided that even without the whole "get rid of the `~`" issue, I don't like it when the non-existant parts of buffers are a different color.

Lastly, I'm trying to learn about vim colorschemes in general, since I'm planning to write a plugin that will need some other tricks like figuring out the colors from schemes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two approaches here:

1. Use `hi NonText`. Not alone, but with `:redir`, of course. I won’t describe it more verbose because I personally don’t like any solution using `:redir` for a number of reasons (they are: 1. requires parsing 2. no nested redirections 3. no way to know whether redirection is active).
2. Use `synIDattr()` and `hlID()`:

   ```
   let bgcolor=synIDattr(hlID('NonText'), 'bg#')
   ```

   will assign something in form `"#rrggbb"` (just `"N"` in terminal) to variable `bgcolor`, or `-1` if background was not defined for this group. You can use this to construct `:hi` command (regular background should be defined in `Normal` group).
3. Just use

   ```
   hi link NonText Ignore
   ```

   . Works unless your colorscheme has redefined `Ignore` group so that it actually *is* shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
hi NonText guibg=bg
```

How about that?

---

***EDIT after clarification from the OP:***

Okey, let's go  from the start. For now I'd put writing of a plugin on hold for a while until you get acquinted with the basic Vim settings and language. The characters, one of which is the `~` you're trying to hide, are so called *list characters*, and they can be defined in the `listchars` option. What yours are you can see by `set listchars?`. They can also be turned on/off (visible or invisible, I mean) by either `set list` / `set nolist`, or toggled on/off with `set invlist`.

The `NonText` highlighting group is the one that "covers" the display of those characters, but really the way to turn them on/off is via the setting, not via overwriting the background/foreground color of that group. Therefore my original confusion over your intentions. There is also a highlighting group `SpecialKey` that you might also find interesting, since it cover some cases.

Comment: I tried something like that. In fact, I have an autocmd that does this:  hi NonText guifg=bg. But as far as I can tell, it's setting the gui foreground (guifg) to the background of the same line, i.e. the NonText background. Am I missing something? Now that I think about it, I have no idea where "bg" is defined...

Comment: @EdanMaor - But why would you want to set "hi NonText guifg=bg"? If you wish to turn off NonText then "set nolist" or "set invlist" to toggle it. In any case, "hi NonText guibg=bg" will set the NonText backgr. to Normal background. "bg" is the Normal background, and fg foreground respectively.

Comment: Although, I must confess, I'm a little puzzled as to what you're trying to accomplish with this in general.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what invlist is. I'll edit my question to add my goals.

Comment: I think what the OP wants to know can be expressed as: how to get the current value of a given highlight group attribute? Of course you can use `:hi NonText`, but that simply lists it. He really wants to have the value in a variable, to play with it in VimScript

Comment: @sidyll: That's exactly right, much better than I put it. I hope the goals I listed above in the edit also make it clear *why* I want this.

Comment: @EdanMaor Sure, it's quite more clear now. I was also confused with the first version of your question :-) By the way, a very interesting question.

Comment: @Idigas - I know about listchars and set list (more or less). But even with set nolist, the ~ character still appears in front of non-existant lines. Are you sure the ~ character in front of non-existant lines is considered a listchar?

Comment: @Idigas - Also, even assuming that it is, I'd still be interested in a generic way of making all colorschemes use the same color for the background of the non-existant part of the buffer as for the regular part. Btw, thanks for taking the time to answer me! Appreciated.

Comment: @EdanMaor - No, sorry (I just got what you ment), ~ at the non existant lines is not part of listchars. For what I know, that part is hardcoded as ~. Your only way to make those invisible would be autocmd ... fg=bg, from what I can tell.